# mkdir in accessory drive

Tags: hardware

Ubuntu 14.10 ext4 With a system in drive (sda) and a drive (sdb) which is a separate hard drive. I have made directories in the former without difficulty but not in the latter. I can place and access files into sdb but I have not figured out how to make directories in sdb. Comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a single partition on sdb (sdb1), and it is mounted as /mnt/data for example, you can make a directory using "mkdir /mnt/data/newdirname"

you can put sudo in front of the command if it says permission denied, and then follow up with a "sudo chown yourusername /mnt/data/newdirname" so your user account can create new files and folders inside the newdirname folder in the future without using sudo.

you could also do the chown on the main sdb mount "sudo chown yourusername /mnt/data" to allow new folders in the "root" folder of the sdb1 mount without requiring sudo.